# Finding center point of a circle intersecting at one point with another

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a problem grasping how can I calculate following:

Given circle $A$ with radius $r_A$ and center point $S_A = (r_A, r_A)$ and circle B with radius $r_B$ and center point $S_B = (2r_A, d)$ calculate $d$ knowing that circles intersect in one point only and $d$ is smallest possible.

And I'm stuck with even starting it. Tried drawing it, but got to a point I just created following set of equations:

$\begin{cases} (x - r_A)^2 + (y - r_A)^2 \mbox{=} {r_A}^2 \\ (x - 2r_A)^2 + (y - d)^2={r_B}^2 \end{cases}$

This however gets me nowhere since I have 2 equations and 3 variables. What am I missing here?

Comment: `What am I missing here?` You are not using yet the condition that there is *one* single point of intersection i.e. the circles are tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you are missing is the one of a line connecting points $(r_A,r_A)$ and $(2r_A,d)$. The intersection point $(x_P,y_P)$ is also on this line.

The easiest way to solve it, however, is by drawing it and realising that the intersection point $(x_P,y_P)$ is along this line and the distance between it and the point $(r_A,r_A)$ is $r_A$.

Comment: Doh.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$r_a^2 + (r_a-d)^2 = (r_a+r_b)^2$

Comment: The vertical is $r_A {-} d$ - take $r_B$ very small to see this.